# Postgres 9.3 json Equality

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I intend to know if there is a way to know if a json exist already on my table.
Please take a look on my scenario:

I have some criteria when creating a product on my database already was made. The criteria can change but cannot have two identical criteria on it. To do so

On my Postgres 9.3 database i define a criteria as a json column of a TableA.

```
criteria_json = {'Product': 'toy',
          'code': 'AB123',
          'detail': ['blue','square']}
```

i would like to check if this criteria already exist by asking if this entire json already exists on my database table.

it would be nice that this equality query was so simple as :

```
SELECT *
FROM criteria = criteria_json;
```

I read this post about [Querying JSON in Postgres](http://this%20post) which talks about how to do with jsonb . i would like to know:

if there is any inconvenient by using jsonb attending with the example above? 
 A: It wont work on my postgres version.

if there is another approaches to take into consideration?
 Attending to my version should i use string comparison instead json approach?

Comment: In most cases JSONB is the better choice anyway

Comment: If you stick with `json`, the most simple solution will be `SELECT * FROM criteria::jsonb = criteria_json::jsonb` anyway.

Comment: @pozs, it wont work on my postgresql version. In fact i believe that is the answer for the first question. I'm almost convince that this is not possible on my psql version.

Comment: Then this might be a good time to upgrade to 9.4 (or the upcoming 9.5).